# XslCompiledTransform thread safety

Tags: .net, multithreading, xslcompiledtransform

MSDN for .NET System.Xml.Xsl.**XslCompiledTransform** Class states:

> ### Thread Safety
>
> **[1]** The XslCompiledTransform object is thread safe once it has been
>   loaded. In other words, after the Load method has successfully
>   completed, the Transform method can be called simultaneously from
>   multiple threads.
>
> **[2]** If the Load method is called again in one thread while the Transform
>   method is being called in another thread, the XslCompiledTransform
>   object finishes executing the Transform call by continuing to use the
>   old state. The new state is used when the Load method successfully
>   completes.
>
> **[3]** Note  The Load method is not thread safe when called simultaneously
>   from multiple threads.

I am (fairly) sure that paragraphs **[1]** & **[2]** are referring to `Load()`/`Transform()` being called (in multiple threads) on the *same* `XslCompiledTransform` object instance. But for **[3]**, does anyone know whether they mean simultaneous `Load()`s on the *same* instance, or whether (there is something static which means that) you must mutually exclude concurrent `Load()`s from *all* instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code in ILSpy there is no visible static synchronization construct. You can call `Load()` on different instances from different threads.

Predictably, `Load` will instanciate a XSLT compiler and compile the stylesheet to an internal object that will later be used by the Transform methods. That explains [1]: once the transform has been compiled it can be called from different threads as the internal object is now read-only.

Calling `Load` again will recompile the internal object so it must be synchronized with any Transform currently going, that accounts for [2].

Calling the compiler simultaneously from different threads would create a race to build the final internal transform object ([3]). Different instance are independent though, they all have their own internal transform object and they instanciate a new compiler each time Load is called.